# How decode MongoDB request from tcpdump?

Tags: mongodb, bson, tcpdump

I have a log with binary data from TCP dump.
I know that there were some requests from mongodb driver (in BSON) format.
And my question is: is there a way to figure out what the original request was?
I've tried  to apply BSON directly to the binary I have from tcpdump, but looks like it's not valid.Could it be that there are some other protocols between TCP and BSON?

It would really help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think with Wireshark it should be possible to "decode" the MongoDB traffic: https://wiki.wireshark.org/Mongo (Mongo Wire Protocol (MONGO)).

I do not think that you can use the dump directly to create BSON data. I think you should decode it first. I think the TCP protocol itself has its overhead beside the payload which is included in your dump.